# responsive navigation bar css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement a responsive top navigation bar into my website. After several trials it's still not working properly and I can't understand where I went wrong.

Could you please tell me if there are any mistakes ?

I attached below the script for the top navigation bar and the script for responsive.

Thank you very much for your help.
Turo

```css
    #main_nav {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        position: -webkit-sticky;
        margin: collapse;
        border-bottom: 0.2em solid #F8FBF9;
        z-index: 10;
        box-shadow: 0.2em 0.3em 0.8em #E5E4E3;
    }

    #main_nav ul {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #main_nav ul li {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 19.7%;
    }

    #main_nav ul li a{
        color: #FF0D90;
        padding: 1em 0;
        font-family: Monaco, monospace;
        font-weight: lighter;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        }

    #main_nav ul li a:hover {
        color: #5CA3F9;
        background-color: #F8FBF9;
    }



    .sel_nav{
        background-color: #FAFCFB;
    } 


    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) { /* CSS Rules */

        body {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin-right: 0;
            margin-left: 0;
            overflow: scroll;
        }

    #main_nav {
            position: relative;
            margin-right: 0;
            margin-left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #main_nav ul {
            width: 19%;
            padding: 1%;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0;
        }


        #main_nav ul li {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            vertical-align: middle;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0 auto;
            margin-left: 120%;

        }

        #main_nav ul li a {
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            padding: 0.5em 3em 0.2em 1.5em;

        }
```

Comment: show your html code

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I edited the main post and put it there since it's too long for a comment.

Comment: can you explain what your issuse??

Comment: do you want to show the nav in one line??

Comment: thanks for your reply, I would like to have every element of the navigation bar one below the other when in responsive. Normally, if I open the site on a computer, these elements of the navigation bar are one next to the orther but when I open it with a mobile device I would like to have them one below the other.  My code doesnt' work well, maybe because of the margins or the padding..

Comment: that what you want to see in mobile:https://i.stack.imgur.com/8p7jF.jpg

Comment: yes, I would also like to have the same margin for left and right because the anchors shoud be centered and fix the padding of the anchor element..

Comment: like this: https://ibb.co/g8ma0J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code, it should work. You had some unnecessary `width` and `padding` in your code and you don't need to use `display: inline-block;` for each and every elements. Here's a cleaner code:

```css
#main_nav {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  margin: collapse;
  border-bottom: 0.2em solid #F8FBF9;
  box-shadow: 0.2em 0.3em 0.8em #E5E4E3;
  width: 100%;
}

#main_nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 0;
}

#main_nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#main_nav ul li a {
  color: #FF0D90;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Monaco, monospace;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 1.5em 1.5em;
}

#main_nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #5CA3F9;
  background-color: #F8FBF9;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #main_nav {
    display: block;
  }
  #main_nav ul {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
  #main_nav ul li {
    display: block;
  }
  #main_nav ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.5em 3em;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav id="main_nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="pagina2.html">NATURA</a></li>
    <li><a href="pagina3.html">CITTA'</a></li>
    <li><a href="pagina4.html">IMMAGINI</a></li>
    <li><a href="pagina5.html">CONTATTI</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

To test responsiveness, test it out at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ukfqncoh/).

Comment: thanks for your help, however I was wondering if it would be possible to have the same margin for left and right because the anchors shoud be centered and fix the padding of the anchor element..

Comment: sorry, I can't understand...the links are already centered, isn't it??

Comment: you can always play with the `padding` of `#main_nav ul li a`

Comment: thanks now it's working but how can I still have the hover with the same size as before? I mean, the grey box when I pass the mouse on a link now it's only on the text butbefore was bigger..I would like to have something like this: https://ibb.co/iFRLjd

Comment: Well, add some padding (`padding: 1.5em 1.5em;`) in `#main_nav ul li a {}`. I guess, this should solve your issue.